# Gitlab-ci can build docker image, but can't run it

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'am new to gitlab-ci. Probably i have problem with git-lab runner or on my gitlab-ci.yml file.
Script on my image use whois command.

gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: docker:18

services:
 - docker:dind 

stages:
 - build
 - test

before_script:
 - docker info

build:
 stage: build
 script:
  - echo "build"
  - docker build -t image.

test:
 stage: test
 script:
  - echo "test"
  - docker run -i image 185.33.37.131
```

test returns

```
$ docker run -i image 185.33.37.131
Unable to find image 'image:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for image, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'.
See 'docker run --help'.
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 125
```

docker info returns suspect value

```
$ docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
.
.
.
Successfully built 64f54ee594e7
Successfully tagged image:latest
```

Comment: You are building an image tagged `image` and, at least according to the output, running an image tagged `ip_info`. Is this the entire source code?

Answer (score 1):

You are building the image in one GitLab job and then trying to run it in another one. Each job is isolated from the others, so the image would no longer exist in the test job. You should push the image to a docker registry after building it and then pull it from the registry when you want to run it.